# How to reference response components in OpenAPI?

Tags: openapi, swagger-editor

I am writing an OpenAPI definition for my API.
I am using `components` for responses, but Swagger Editor shows an error when I try to reference these components:

```yaml
responses:
  - $ref: '#/components/responses/401'
  - $ref: '#/components/responses/400'
```

[image]

What is the correct way to reference response components?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way to reference response components is:

```yaml
responses:
  '400':
    $ref: '#/components/responses/400'
  '401':
    $ref: '#/components/responses/401'
```

That is, `responses` is a *map* (not an array/list) where the keys are HTTP status codes and the values are response definitions.

> Can you override the response description when referencing the component?

This is possible in OpenAPI 3.1, but not in earlier versions. Put the new `description` alongside the `$ref`:

```yaml
# openapi: 3.1.0

responses:

  '400':
    $ref: '#/components/responses/400'
    description: This description overrides that of the referenced response.

  '401':
    $ref: '#/components/responses/401'
    description: This description overrides that of the referenced response.
```

Comment: tks Helen, great answer

Comment: Do you know if you can override the response description when referencing the component?

Comment: @AxM it's possible in OAS 3.1, see the updated answer.