# Combine multiple annotations into one

Tags: java, quarkus

Im using Java 11 Quarkus 2.9.2 Final and I would like to avoid duplication of a set of annotations:

```
      @APIResponse(
          responseCode = "401",
          description = "Unauthorized",
          content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)),
      @APIResponse(
          responseCode = "403",
          description = "Forbidden",
          content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)),
      @APIResponse(
          responseCode = "404",
          description = "Not Found",
          content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```

My plan is to make a custom annotation for it like @APIResponses40X().

Is this possible? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are asking for is possible, but you can reduce by a lot duplicated code using Quarkus OpenAPI merge feature:

> a request to /q/openapi will serve the combined OpenAPI document from the static file and the model generated from application endpoints code

Just create a static openapi.yml file and define reusable responses for status codes.
Every `@APIResponse` owns a `ref` property used to `ref`erence an element in your OpenAPI file; just reference the correct response.

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/
[How to reference response components in OpenAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69173235/how-to-reference-response-components-in-openapi)